# Sending a value through render() in grails controller

Tags: model-view-controller, grails, groovy

This is probably one very simple question to answer, but I can't output the variable I am trying to send to a view through a controller in the Grails Framework.

```
render(view: 'parseerror', error: it)
```

That's my code in my controller, it renders the view correctly but as soon as I am trying to call the variable through `${error}` it outputs nothing. It should output a string since when I print the iterator, the console output: `The example string`

Thanks for helping me out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map key is "errors", not "error", but I belive, you want to achieve something similar to this code:

```
render( view: 'parseerror', model: [ 'error': error ] )
```